# PCA : eigen values vs eigen vectors vs loadings in python vs R?

Tags: r, scikit-learn, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to calculate PCA loadings of a dataset. The more I read about it, the more I get confused because "*loadings*" is used differently at many places.

I am using [sklearn.decomposition](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) in python for PCA analysis as well as R (using [factomineR](http://factominer.free.fr/index_fr.html) and [factoextra](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factoextra-r-package-easy-multivariate-data-analyses-and-elegant-visualization) libraries) as it provides easy visualization techniques. The following is my understanding:

1. pca.components_ give us the eigen vectors. They give us the directions of maximum variation.
2. pca.explained_variance_ give us the eigen values associated with the eigen vectors.
3. eigenvectors * sqrt(eigen values) = loadings which tell us how principal components (pc's) load the variables.

Now, what I am confused by is:

1. Many forums say that eigen vectors are the loadings. Then, when we multiply the eigen vectors by the sqrt(eigen values) we just get the strength of association. Others say eigenvectors * sqrt(eigen values) = loadings.
2. Eigen vectors squared tells us the contribution of variable to pc? I believe this is equivalent to var$contrib in R.
3. loading squared (eigen vector or eigenvector*sqrt(eigenvalue) I don't know which one) shows how well a pc captures a variable (closer to 1 = variable better explained by a  pc). Is this equivalent of var$cos2 in R? If not what is cos2 in R?
4. Basically I want to know how to understand how well a principal component captures a variable and what is the contribution of a variable to a pc. I think they both are different.
5. What is pca.singular_values_? It is not clear from the documentation.

These [first](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/#:%7E:text=The%20contribution%20of%20a%20variable,total%20cos2%20of%20the%20component) and [second](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another) links that I referred which contains R code with explanation and the statsexchange forum that confused me.

Comment: can you restrict to 1 question?

Comment: @StupidWolf All the questions encompass the gist of PCA analysis. All are related to each other. I am seeking clarification on the PCA terminologies. I hope it does not flout the forum rules.

Comment: I would say you are making it harder for users to address your questions. Does answering one of the questions count as correct?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after much research and going through many papers I have the following,

1. pca.components_ = eigen vectors. Take a transpose so that pc's are columns and variables are rows.

1.a: eigenvector**2 = variable contribution in principal components. If it's close to 1 then a particular pc is well explained by that variable.

In python -> (pow(pca.components_.T),2) [Multiply with 100 if you want percentages and not proportions] [R equivalent -> var$contrib]

2. pca.variance_explained_ = eigen values
3. pca.singular_values_ = singular values obtained from SVD.
   (singular values)**2/(n-1) = eigen values
4. eigen vectors * sqrt(eigen values) = loadings matrix

4.a: vertical sum of squared loading matrix = eigen values. (Given you have taken transpose as explained in step 1)

4.b: horizontal sum of squared loading matrix = observation's variance explained by all  principal components -How much all pc's retain a variables variance after transformation. (Given you have taken transpose as explained in step 1)

In python-> loading matrix = pca.components_.T * sqrt(pca.explained_variance_).

For questions pertaining to r:

var$cos2 = var$cor (Both matrices are same). Given the coordinates of the variables on a factor map, how well it is represented by a particular principal component. Seems like variable and principal component's correlation.

var$contrib = Summarized by point 1. In r:(var.cos2 * 100) / (total cos2 of the component) [PCA analysis in R link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/wiki.php?id_contents=7851#contributions-of-the-variables-to-the-principal-components)

Hope it helps others who are confused by PCA analysis.

Huge thanks to -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another

Comment: this was very re-affirming.
however, shouldn't 4.b (that is, the proportional contribution of a variable to a PC) be simply the squared matrix of eigenvectors? that is, where eigenvectors_matrix = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_.T, columns=column_names, index=features)

after you square the eigenvectors_matrix via  eigenvectors_matrix**2 , you will see that the sum of each column is 1.0, representing the variable's proportional contribution to that PC.